# Delete rows in Multi Index dataframe based on the number of counts of a specific type of occurance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame where I have 2 major indices. One is Group and other is Sub Group. I have 1 column named `latex`.

I want to **delete all the rows if the count of a specific combination of group_subGroup<2**

For Example if I have just 1 entry whose `GroupNumber=103` and `SubGroup=2`, I want to delete it.

My Data looks like this:
[image]

I tried the `groupby` function but unable to get the rows to delete`
[image]

How do I proceed from here and delete all the rows which have just 1 unique combination?

Answer (score 0):

My input data:

```py
>>> df
    Group  SubGroup  latex
0       8         3      3
1       8         3      3
2       6         2      4  # 1 occurrence (6, 2)
3       6         1      2  # 1 occurrence (6, 1)
4       6         3      2  # 1 occurrence (6, 3)
5       9         3      3
6       7         3      2
7       8         2      1  # 1 occurrence (8, 2)
8       9         3      3
9       9         3      2
10      7         1      4
11      9         1      3  # 1 occurrence (9, 1)
12      7         1      4
13      9         3      2
14      7         3      3
```

"Delete all the rows which have just 1 unique combination" means keep all combinations greater or equal than 2:

```py
>>> df.assign(comb=df.groupby(["Group", "SubGroup"])["Group"].transform(len))
    Group  SubGroup  latex  comb
0       8         3      3     2
1       8         3      3     2
2       6         2      4     1  # <- drop
3       6         1      2     1  # <- drop
4       6         3      2     1  # <- drop
5       9         3      3     4
6       7         3      2     2
7       8         2      1     1  # <- drop
8       9         3      3     4
9       9         3      2     4
10      7         1      4     2
11      9         1      3     1  # <- drop
12      7         1      4     2
13      9         3      2     4
14      7         3      3     2

>>> df[df.groupby(["Group", "SubGroup"])["Group"].transform(len).ge(2)]

    Group  SubGroup  latex
0       8         3      3
1       8         3      3
5       9         3      3
6       7         3      2
8       9         3      3
9       9         3      2
10      7         1      4
12      7         1      4
13      9         3      2
14      7         3      3
```

Comment: No , You got it wrong, latex does not tell the `length` of latex. It tell the No of times a combination has occured. For example if I have,  `6,2,4` (your first comment) then it means that the combination of `6,4` has occured 4 times already. I want to delete something which is `M,N,1` in my image. Can you please look at the data. I have edited the original Df that I have.

Comment: Is it possible in your dataframe you have `(6,2,1)` multiple times?

Comment: No, 6 means the The main group, 2 means the sub group and 1 means these things have only once . I have used `.agg('count)`. 1 is the `count`